# Different Summands problem - greedy alogrithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

I am trying to design a function called "distinct_summands" that takes in a positive integer n, to output a list of k distinct integers a1,..., ak such that a1+...+ak= n and k is as large as possible.

Some examples of the test cases are as follows: distinct_summands(8)=[1,2,5], distinct_summands(2)=[2], distinct_summands(14)=[1, 2, 3, 8]. I tested the codes myself for n=1,2,3...,100K. I didn't find any mistakes so far. However, when I submit the code to a black box code tester, I get an "out of index" error.

I tried everything I know to find out what went wrong. But I still don't know what went wrong. I attached my codes below. Can someone let me know what I did wrong?

```
def distinct_summands(n):

    if n <=2: 
        return [n]
    
    remainder = n 

    number_list = list(range(1, n+1))

    prev_pos, curr_pos = 0, 0
    summands = []

    while remainder > number_list[prev_pos]:

        remainder = remainder - number_list[curr_pos]
        prev_pos = curr_pos
        summands.append(number_list[prev_pos])  
    
        if remainder >  2* number_list[curr_pos+1]:                     
            curr_pos += 1 
                
        else:

            curr_pos = remainder -1 
         
    return summands
```

Comment: Is `k` a fixed number? Are you trying to maximize the number of summands using a greedy algorithm?

Comment: I am trying to maximize k such that a1+...+ak = n for some n>=1, where a1, ..., ak are distinct positive integers that are no bigger than n. You are right. I am trying to maximize the number of summands using a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Are the constraints of the problem that n is less than `10**5`? It could also be that you're returning an answer with the wrong length.

Comment: The constraint is 1<=n<=10**9. This problem was posed in a chapter that covers greedy algorithms. I am trying to learn algorithms during my free time. Regarding your comment, if there was an issue with output length, I would get a different error message (instead of the "out of index" error).

Comment: Which website is this? I don't think this code as is is fast enough, but I'm more surprised that it has a runtime error rather than TLE.

Comment: No issue with the runtime. I know it's not fast. I am just trying to have a basic implementation first to get a basic understanding of greedy algorithms. Regarding the website, you can see page 75 in the following link:
 shorturl.at/euJ58

Comment: What code tester are you using?

Comment: My suspicion is `number_list = list(range(1, n+1))` runs into problems if `n` is too large.  And you never need more than `O(sqrt(n))` of those numbers.  Try `number_list = list(range(1, int(2 * n**0.5 + 2)))` instead.

Comment: BrokenBenchmark, I created a tester myself. Coursera has a black-box tester. btilly, thanks for the advice; I will try and get back to you.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can solve this analytically without all the looping. The initial range will be `r = range(1, int(((8 * n + 1)**.5 - 1)//2))`. Then you can take the difference of sum of this range and `n` for the final number. (ie. `return list(r) + [n - sum(r)]`) This will be orders of magnitude faster with large values of `n`.

Comment: @Mark The OP knows that there are more efficient solutions, and is working through material that will teach that.  The question was why this solution didn't work.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks a lot for your answer! That's definitely a better solution. But right now I am trying to learn greedy algorithms. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @btilly, thanks a lot for your answer! I tested the solution you suggested. Unfortunately, it also gave "out of index" error. Interestingly, the user "aropan" suggested a solution that doesn't require creating "number_list". His solution passed the black box test. Thanks so much again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n is large then `number_list = list(range(1, n+1))` need a lot of memory (maybe it is cause `out of index` error). But you use the `number_list` array to get elements only, so I think you can replace `number_list[index]` to `index + 1` and solve your problem:

```py
def distinct_summands(n):

    if n <= 2:
        return [n]

    remainder = n

    prev_pos, curr_pos = 0, 0
    summands = []

    while remainder > prev_pos + 1:

        remainder = remainder - (curr_pos + 1)
        prev_pos = curr_pos
        summands.append(prev_pos + 1)

        if remainder > 2 * (curr_pos + 2):
            curr_pos += 1
        else:
            curr_pos = remainder - 1

    return summands
```